# Backlight on/off button doesn't work on an Asus EEE PC 1005HAB

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, asus, eeepc

I've got an Asus EEE PC 1005HAB, and after upgrading to 11.04 I can no longer use <kbd>Fn+F7</kbd> to turn on/off the screen backlight. The other <kbd>Fn+FX</kbd> keys I've tried so far all work. Is there some standard fix, or should I report this? A quick Google search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Yeah this should probably be a bug report. [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a Eee PC 1005HA to confirm this. Running `dmesg` I get:

> keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 244

The keycode refers to `XF86KbdLightOnOff`, so I think this is a bug.

**Workaround:**

- Use `xrandr -q` to get the monitor's name, should be something like LVDS1.
- Use **[compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/compizconfig-settings-manager)** [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] commands plugin to set hotkeys to:

  - `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off`  change LVDS1 with your monitors name.
  - `xrandr --auto` dont use output with this command, it seems to cause window glitches.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to turn off the backlight of the LCD whenever you want. Just type

```
xset dpms force off
```

and press enter in a terminal, or make a desktop launcher of it and attach it in the unity panel.

If you're using gnome shell then there's a gnome shell extension to attach a desktop launcher to the top panel, then with a single click u can turnoff your lcd.

If it works you can also make a keyboard shortcut for `xset dpms force off`

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 removed several packages from me. One of them was `smartdimmer`. It's package description is:

> Nvidia Geforce 6200Go, Geforce 8, Geforce 9, and other cards contain hardware LCD brightness control. Smartdimmer allows this to be controlled through software.

Try installing it, I do not guarantee anything though.

The logs of the upgrade process can be found in `/var/log/dist-upgrade`, and the log for installed / removed packages in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/history.log`.

Comment: Does `smartdimmer` work for cards other than Nvidia? I can't control screen brightness on my laptop with Intel card even though the brightness meter/slider can be moved up and down.

Comment: I don't think so. Could you try manually setting the brightness level using the `/sys` interface? Run: `cd /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0`, followed by `cat brightness max_brightness`. The first number is your current brightness, the second your maximum brightness. The minimum value is `0` (zero). To change it to `3`, run: `echo 3 | sudo tee brightness`. Please report any errors back.

Comment: Lekensteyn, I think because of my attempts to change brightness (i.e. lower it), the `brightness` output was `0`. I ran the command to change it to three, and after inputting password, output of only `3` was shown. No noticeable change in brightness.

Comment: @Oxwivi: [this bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/773471) may be of interest for you.

Comment: That bug I believe is [due to the kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/740893).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Unity launcher to turnoff the LCD. You can also try this

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

it will open a small window

- in **name** type : `turnofflcd`
- in **command** type : `xset dpms force off`

I read about making a launcher [here on Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10oneiric.html)